# Write a text with multiple lines into a file with JSCH

Tags: java, file, unix, command, jsch

This also a Unix question so, here is the deal: I have a whole String variable in Java, which is the content of an XML file, and I want to write this whole text into a file with one command like:

```
echo "<xml>
        <data>
        </data>
     </xml>" > basic.xml
```

And with this kind of text, unix gives the error that

I have did it with properties files but there were no spaces in it so it did not gave me an error.

I also tried to replace the \n chars with $'\n' like:

```
contentStr=contentStr.replaceAll("\n", "\\$'\n'");
```

but JSCH gave me the unix error.

Any ideas?

Thnx

Ali

Comment: JSCH? The SSH/SCP implementation library? You should also post some sample code so we know what you've tried.

Comment: @dcsohl Edited the sample. Do u mean JSCH code? It is not related with it, because the problem is with the string. It is like, I am passing something like "echo 'a \n b \n' > basic.xml"

Comment: If it's not related then it probably shouldn't be tagged with [jsch] and you shouldn't mention it in the post title. All you're really looking for is help with your replaceAll() invocation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
contentStr=contentStr.replace("\n", "\\n");
contentStr=contentStr.replace("\"", "\\\"");            

writeOperation.setCommand("printf \""+contentStr+"\" > "+source.getPath());
```

That s the answer. Sort of anyway;)

Answer (score 0):

The example you give for replaceAll is not quite right. You are replacing the carriage return character with a backslash, followed by a dollar, followed by singlequote, carriage return, single quote. I think you are looking to replace it with backslash, dollar, singlequote, backslash, n, singlequote? Get rid of the actual carriage return and replace it with a sort of escape sequence?

Try `contentStr=contentStr.replace("\n", "$'\\n'");`

The thing to bear in mind about `replaceAll()` is that you can get funny results if you have backslashes or dollars in the second string. From the docs: "Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above, and backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string." Using `replace()` is a much better option here.

Comment: Nop, did not worked, but I found out. Thanks anyway. Just check the answer